# Raspberry Pi Not Working

Tags: hdmi

I got a Raspberry Pi 2 and it did not work with the newest version of NOOBS (flashing LEDs).  There is nothing on the TV/monitor.  It just says there is no HDMI input.  I tried it with an older version and the lights stopped flashing, but still the same problem with the video output.  I tried re-installing and re-formatting the OS and SD card multiple times with no luck.  I tried multiple different power supplies with sufficient amperage, and multiple TVs.  Still dose not work.  I ended up returning the Pi and got a new one.  I am getting the same problem the the new one.

Comment: forgot to add, I tested the HDMI cable on a laptop and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the type of flashing of the green (ACT) LED, you can figure out what is wrong (or at least what ballpark it's in) by looking at [this page](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up).

Too long didn't read version:

**Green LED:** *ACT LED*
------ **Red LED:** *PWR LED*

## Simple Issues

- **No PWR LED** - No power.
- **PWR LED Blinking** - Not enough power.
- **PWR LED but no ACT LED (For Pi 1s)** - Problem with SD card.
- **PWR LED on ACT LED on and *STEADY* (For Pi 2)** - Problem with SD card.

## ACT LED Flashing in Specific Pattern

- **1 flash** - OS too old. FIX: Use OS written after September 2013
- **2 flashes** - SD Card cannot be read.

***FOR SOFTWARE (OSs) BEFORE OCTOBER 2012:***

- **3 flashes** - loader.bin not found
- **4 flashes** - loader.bin not launched
- **5 flashes** - start.elf not found
- **6 flashes** - start.elf not launched
- **7 flashes** - kernel.img not found

***FOR SOFTWARE (OSs) AFTER OCTOBER 2012:***

- **3 flashes** - start.elf not found
- **4 flashes** - start.elf not launched
- **7 flashes** - kernel.img not found
- **8 flashes** - SDRAM not recognised. FIX: Newer
  bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware.

Comment: Both LEDs are solid without the SD card...

Comment: > PWR LED on ACT LED on and STEADY (For Pi 2) - Problem with SD card.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting the board with your hdmi plugged in and without a sd card. One should see the test rainbow screen. If not then there is a malfunction either in your display, cable, and/or the raspberry pi.