# No video output on Raspberry Pi Zero, LED flashing

Tags: hdmi, video, led, output

So I just got a Raspberry Pi Zero and an SD card with NOOBS pre-installed. I placed the SD card onto the RPi as well as a keyboard and a power supply. I plugged the RPi onto two different monitors, however there was no video output (HDMI) on both. I tried cycling through pressing 1-4 on my keyboard, however nothing worked.

There is a constant green LED flashing, apparently this means there is some sort of error on boot up? I'm very new to all of this, what would you guys recommend that I do?

Comment: Is your led flashing in some sort of pattern? Like 3 flashes at a time?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said, you seem to be plugging the HDMI cables last. You need to plug the HDMI cable in before you plug in the power cable usually - especially if you're starting up for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If your ACT led is flashing in a pattern, and not irradically, you should refer to [my answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41455/33979). The easiest fix for basically all of the possible problems is to reformat your sd card.